# WxPython Program keeps on crashing the console

Tags: python, wxpython

I've been working on this program for quite some time. Its basically this shop keeping program and for some reason, whenever i attempt to open and view any supplier details, the program crashes after i view it. The console just wont let me run any other commands.

Here is the full code:

```
#Place imports here
import wx
from sqlite3 import *
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------            
text1='Name:'
text2='Address:'
text3='Contact Number:'
text4='Alternate Number:'
text5='Email ID:'
text6='CST Number :'
text7='VAT Number:'
global datalist

#GUI Starts here

class MainMenu(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self,parent,id):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,id,'Main Window',size=(500,600))
        mainpanel=wx.Panel(self)
        status=self.CreateStatusBar()
        wx.Frame.CenterOnScreen(self)
        mainmenubar=wx.MenuBar()

        filemenu=wx.Menu()
        fileitem=filemenu.Append(wx.ID_EXIT,'&Save and Quit','This will quit the application')
        mainmenubar.Append(filemenu, '&File')   

        usermenu=wx.Menu()
        useritem1=usermenu.Append(wx.NewId(), '&View User Details', 'This will allow you to see the current user details')
        useritem2=usermenu.Append(wx.NewId(), '&Change User Details', 'This will change the existing user details')
        mainmenubar.Append(usermenu, '&User')

        suppliermenu=wx.Menu()
        supplieritem1=suppliermenu.Append(wx.NewId(),'&New Supplier','This will allow you to a new Supplier to the database')
        supplieritem2=suppliermenu.Append(wx.NewId(), '&View Supplier Details', 'This will allow you to view any existing supplier details')
        supplieritem3=suppliermenu.Append(wx.NewId(), '&Change Supplier Details', 'This will allow you to change the supplier details')
        mainmenubar.Append(suppliermenu, '&Supplier')         



        self.SetMenuBar(mainmenubar)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU,self.ViewUserDetail,useritem1)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU,self.ChangeUserDetail,useritem2)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnQuit, fileitem)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.ViewSupplierDetail,supplieritem2)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.NewSupplier,supplieritem1)

    def OnQuit(self, e):
        self.Close()
        conn.commit()
        c.close()

    def ViewUserDetail(self,e):
        global datalist
        datalist=[row for row in c.execute('SELECT * FROM User') ]

        self.new=ViewUserDetail(parent=None, id=-1)
        self.new.Show()


    def ChangeUserDetail(self,e):
        self.new=ChangeUserDetail(parent=None, id=-1)
        self.new.Show()

    def ViewSupplierDetail(self,e):
        global datalist2
        datalist2=[row for row in c.execute('SELECT * FROM Supplier') ]
        self.new=ViewSupplierDetail(parent=None, id=-1)
        self.new.Show()

    def NewSupplier(self,e):
        self.new=NewSupplier(parent=None, id=-1)
        self.new.Show()


conn=Connection('E:\Python Software\ShopTest\SystemData.db')
c=conn.cursor()
try:
    c.execute('''CREATE TABLE User
            (Name, Address, Contact_No, Alternate_No, Email_ID, CST_No, VAT_No, ID Primary Key) ''')
except OperationalError:
    pass

try:
    c.execute('''CREATE TABLE Supplier
            (Name, Address, Contact_No, Alternate_No, Email_ID, CST_No, VAT_No, ID Primary Key) ''')
except OperationalError:
    pass    





class ChangeUserDetail(wx.MiniFrame):
            def __init__(self,parent,id):
                wx.MiniFrame.__init__(self,parent,id,'Change User Details',size=(350,490))
                wx.MiniFrame.CenterOnScreen(self)

                changeuserdetailpanel=wx.Panel(self)


                sta = wx.StaticText(changeuserdetailpanel, label=text1, pos=(10,9))
                stb = wx.StaticText(changeuserdetailpanel, label=text2, pos=(10,89))
                stc = wx.StaticText(changeuserdetailpanel, label=text3, pos=(10,169))
                std = wx.StaticText(changeuserdetailpanel, label=text4, pos=(10,219))
                ste = wx.StaticText(changeuserdetailpanel, label=text5, pos=(10,269))
                stf = wx.StaticText(changeuserdetailpanel, label=text6, pos=(10,319))
                stg = wx.StaticText(changeuserdetailpanel, label=text7, pos=(10,369))


                global tcl1,tcl2,tcl3,tcl4,tcl5,tcl6,tcl7,tcl8,tcl9

                tcl1 = wx.TextCtrl(changeuserdetailpanel, -1, "", size=(175, 25),pos=(145,7))
                tcl2 = wx.TextCtrl(changeuserdetailpanel, -1, "", size=(175, 25),pos=(145,57))  #,style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)
               tcl3 = wx.TextCtrl(changeuserdetailpanel, -1, "", size=(175, 25),pos=(145,87))
                tcl4 = wx.TextCtrl(changeuserdetailpanel, -1, "", size=(175, 25),pos=(145,114))
                tcl5 = wx.TextCtrl(changeuserdetailpanel, -1, "", size=(175, 25),pos=(145,167))
                tcl6 = wx.TextCtrl(changeuserdetailpanel, -1, "", size=(175, 25),pos=(145,217))
                tcl7 = wx.TextCtrl(changeuserdetailpanel, -1, "", size=(175, 25),pos=(145,267))
                tcl8 = wx.TextCtrl(changeuserdetailpanel, -1, "", size=(175, 25),pos=(145,317))
                tcl9 = wx.TextCtrl(changeuserdetailpanel, -1, "", size=(175, 25),pos=(145,367))


                submitbutton=wx.Button(changeuserdetailpanel, label='Submit', pos=(60,410),size=(100,30))            
                cancelbutton=wx.Button(changeuserdetailpanel, label='Cancel', pos=(180,410),size=(100,30))
                self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,self.OnSubmit,submitbutton)
                self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,self.OnCancel,cancelbutton)

            def OnSubmit(self,e):

                add1=tcl2.GetValue()+ '\n'
                add2=tcl3.GetValue()+ '\n'
                add3=tcl4.GetValue()

                user_name=tcl1.GetValue()
                user_add=add1+add2+add3
                user_contact=tcl5.GetValue()
                user_alt=tcl6.GetValue()
                user_email=tcl7.GetValue()
                user_cst=tcl8.GetValue()
                user_vat=tcl9.GetValue()

                global user_list

                user_list=[user_name,user_add,user_contact,user_alt,user_email,user_cst,user_vat,1]



                c.execute('DELETE FROM User WHERE ID=1')
                c.execute('INSERT INTO User(Name,Address,Contact_No,     Alternate_No, Email_ID, CST_No, VAT_No, ID) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)',user_list)             



                self.Close(True)
            def OnCancel(self,e):
                self.Close(True)


class ViewUserDetail(wx.MiniFrame):

            def __init__(self,parent,id):
                wx.MiniFrame.__init__(self,parent,id,'View User Details',size=(350,390))
                wx.MiniFrame.CenterOnScreen(self)

                viewuserdetailpanel=wx.Panel(self)
                closebutton=wx.Button(viewuserdetailpanel, label='Close', pos=(100,310),size=(100,30))

                st1=wx.StaticText(viewuserdetailpanel, label=text1, pos=(10,10))
                st2=wx.StaticText(viewuserdetailpanel, label=text2, pos=(10,50))
                st3=wx.StaticText(viewuserdetailpanel, label=text3, pos=(10,120))
                st4=wx.StaticText(viewuserdetailpanel, label=text4, pos=(10,160))
                st5=wx.StaticText(viewuserdetailpanel, label=text5, pos=(10,200))
                st6=wx.StaticText(viewuserdetailpanel, label=text6, pos=(10,240))
                st7=wx.StaticText(viewuserdetailpanel, label=text7, pos=(10,280))



                sta=wx.StaticText(viewuserdetailpanel, label=datalist[0][0], pos=(170,10))
                stb=wx.StaticText(viewuserdetailpanel, label=datalist[0][1], pos=(170,50))                    
                stc=wx.StaticText(viewuserdetailpanel, label=datalist[0][2], pos=(170,120))
                std=wx.StaticText(viewuserdetailpanel, label=datalist[0][3], pos=(170,160))
                ste=wx.StaticText(viewuserdetailpanel, label=datalist[0][4], pos=(170,200))
                stf=wx.StaticText(viewuserdetailpanel, label=datalist[0][5], pos=(170,240))
                stg=wx.StaticText(viewuserdetailpanel, label=datalist[0][6], pos=(170,280))



                self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,self.OnClose,closebutton)



            def OnClose(self,e):
                self.Close(True) 

class NewSupplier(wx.MiniFrame):
            def __init__(self,parent,id):
               wx.MiniFrame.__init__(self,parent,id,'New Supplier',size=(350,490))
                wx.MiniFrame.CenterOnScreen(self)

                newsupplierpanel=wx.Panel(self)


                sta = wx.StaticText(newsupplierpanel, label=text1, pos=(10,9))
                stb = wx.StaticText(newsupplierpanel, label=text2, pos=(10,89))
                stc = wx.StaticText(newsupplierpanel, label=text3, pos=(10,169))
                std = wx.StaticText(newsupplierpanel, label=text4, pos=(10,219))
                ste = wx.StaticText(newsupplierpanel, label=text5, pos=(10,269))
                stf = wx.StaticText(newsupplierpanel, label=text6, pos=(10,319))
                stg = wx.StaticText(newsupplierpanel, label=text7, pos=(10,369))


                global tcl1,tcl2,tcl3,tcl4,tcl5,tcl6,tcl7,tcl8,tcl9

                tcl1 = wx.TextCtrl(newsupplierpanel, -1, "", size=(175, 25),pos=(145,7))
                tcl2 = wx.TextCtrl(newsupplierpanel, -1, "", size=(175, 25),pos=(145,57))  #,style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)
                tcl3 = wx.TextCtrl(newsupplierpanel, -1, "", size=(175, 25),pos=(145,87))
                tcl4 = wx.TextCtrl(newsupplierpanel, -1, "", size=(175, 25),pos=(145,114))
                tcl5 = wx.TextCtrl(newsupplierpanel, -1, "", size=(175, 25),pos=(145,167))
                tcl6 = wx.TextCtrl(newsupplierpanel, -1, "", size=(175, 25),pos=(145,217))
                tcl7 = wx.TextCtrl(newsupplierpanel, -1, "", size=(175, 25),pos=(145,267))
                tcl8 = wx.TextCtrl(newsupplierpanel, -1, "", size=(175, 25),pos=(145,317))
                tcl9 = wx.TextCtrl(newsupplierpanel, -1, "", size=(175, 25),pos=(145,367))


                submitbutton=wx.Button(newsupplierpanel, label='Submit', pos=(60,410),size=(100,30))            
                cancelbutton=wx.Button(newsupplierpanel, label='Cancel', pos=(180,410),size=(100,30))
                self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,self.OnSubmit,submitbutton)
                self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,self.OnCancel,cancelbutton)

            def OnSubmit(self,e):

                add1=tcl2.GetValue()+ '\n'
                add2=tcl3.GetValue()+ '\n'
                add3=tcl4.GetValue()

                supplier_name=tcl1.GetValue()
                supplier_add=add1+add2+add3
                supplier_contact=tcl5.GetValue()
                supplier_alt=tcl6.GetValue()
                supplier_email=tcl7.GetValue()
                supplier_cst=tcl8.GetValue()
                supplier_vat=tcl9.GetValue()

                global supplierlist

                supplier_list=    [supplier_name,supplier_add,supplier_contact,supplier_alt,supplier_email,supplier_cst,supplier_vat]



                #c.execute('DELETE FROM User WHERE ID=1')
                c.execute('INSERT INTO Supplier(Name,Address,Contact_No,     Alternate_No, Email_ID, CST_No, VAT_No, ID) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)',supplier_list)             



                self.Close(True)
            def OnCancel(self,e):
                self.Close(True)


class ViewSupplierDetail(wx.MiniFrame):

            def __init__(self,parent,id):


                viewsupplierbox=wx.SingleChoiceDialog(None, 'Choose Supplier', 'View Supplier Details', datalist2[0][0])
                if viewsupplierbox.ShowModal()==wx.ID_OK:
                    answer=viewsupplierbox.GetStringSelection()



                    wx.MiniFrame.__init__(self,parent,id,'View Supplier Details',size=(320,350))
                    wx.MiniFrame.CenterOnScreen(self)
                    viewsupplierdetailpanel=wx.Panel(self)


                    st1=wx.StaticText(viewsupplierdetailpanel, label=text1, pos=(10,10))
                    st2=wx.StaticText(viewsupplierdetailpanel, label=text2, pos=(10,50))
                    st3=wx.StaticText(viewsupplierdetailpanel, label=text3, pos=(10,90))
                    st4=wx.StaticText(viewsupplierdetailpanel, label=text4, pos=(10,130))
                    st5=wx.StaticText(viewsupplierdetailpanel, label=text5, pos=(10,170))
                    st6=wx.StaticText(viewsupplierdetailpanel, label=text6, pos=(10,210))
                    st7=wx.StaticText(viewsupplierdetailpanel, label=text7, pos=(10,250))

                    closebutton=wx.Button(viewsupplierdetailpanel, label='Ok', pos=(110,270),size=(90,30))            

                    self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,self.OnClose,closebutton)


            def OnClose(self,e):

                self.Close(True) 

 if __name__=='__main__':
    app=wx.App()
    frame=MainMenu(parent=None,id=-1)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

The Portion giving me trouble is this:
    class ViewSupplierDetail(wx.MiniFrame):

```
            def __init__(self,parent,id):


                viewsupplierbox=wx.SingleChoiceDialog(None, 'Choose Supplier', 'View Supplier Details', datalist2[0][0])
                if viewsupplierbox.ShowModal()==wx.ID_OK:
                    answer=viewsupplierbox.GetStringSelection()



                    wx.MiniFrame.__init__(self,parent,id,'View Supplier Details',size=(320,350))
                    wx.MiniFrame.CenterOnScreen(self)
                    viewsupplierdetailpanel=wx.Panel(self)


                    st1=wx.StaticText(viewsupplierdetailpanel, label=text1, pos=(10,10))
                    st2=wx.StaticText(viewsupplierdetailpanel, label=text2, pos=(10,50))
                    st3=wx.StaticText(viewsupplierdetailpanel, label=text3, pos=(10,90))
                    st4=wx.StaticText(viewsupplierdetailpanel, label=text4, pos=(10,130))
                    st5=wx.StaticText(viewsupplierdetailpanel, label=text5, pos=(10,170))
                    st6=wx.StaticText(viewsupplierdetailpanel, label=text6, pos=(10,210))
                    st7=wx.StaticText(viewsupplierdetailpanel, label=text7, pos=(10,250))

                    closebutton=wx.Button(viewsupplierdetailpanel, label='Ok', pos=(110,270),size=(90,30))            

                    self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,self.OnClose,closebutton)


            def OnClose(self,e):

                self.Close(True)
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: Any errors in the log?

Comment: Nope. None. I even tried running it through the python console. I usually work in Canopy.

Comment: "crashes" is not a problem description - what exactly happens? Please ask only one question in one post.

Comment: When i say crashes, i mean that the program exits fine, but the console is unusable and has to be restarted, which shows that the current program is still running.

Answer (score 0):

After playing around with this a bit, I'm guessing the connection to SQLite is never closed, which could be the hang up. You should really put the connection code into your Main class and then pass the connection object to the other classes on their instantiation. Then each of the other classes can create a cursor object to use for their queries, inserts, selects, etc. When you close your other frames, you can clean up your cursors. Then when you close your MainMenu class, you can close your database connection and it should return correctly.